# VB.Net SQLite Deletion not persisting?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Trying to delete a row, not receiving any exceptions but deletion does not persist when I reload the DB.  Helpful comments only, please.  I am not posting all of the code from my project, only the relevant parts for my question.

```
Private testsList As BindingList(Of ProxyTest)

Private Sub DeleteTest(test As ProxyTest)
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM tests WHERE url = @url", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", test.URL)
            ExecuteNonQuery(conn, cmd)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(conn As SQLiteConnection, sqlCommand As SQLiteCommand)
    Dim affectedRows As Integer = 0
    sqlCommand.Connection = conn
    affectedRows = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Return affectedRows
End Function

Private Sub btnRemoveTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveTest.Click
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvTests.SelectedRows
        DeleteTest(testsList(row.Index))
        testsList.RemoveAt(row.Index)
    Next
End Sub
```

My SQLite DB Schema

> CREATE TABLE `tests` ( `url` TEXT, `validationString` TEXT,
>   `invalidationString` TEXT, `isValid` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`url`) )

Comment: When you use debug the database is regenerated empty on every run. Build your project then play with it and the data will stay stored in the DB

Comment: @Mederic Can you elaborate a bit?  I am building my project and playing with it.  I left out the code for adding and loading via SELECT, because they are beyond the scope of my question.  The adding part is persisting, deletion is not.  Although the code for adding is exactly the same except for the statement itself of course.

Comment: don't know how to explain better: Every time you run the project in Debug Mode the Database will be regenerated if you created the DB with VS. Hence you need to build the project and test it not in debug to see the data staying in the DB even on application close

Comment: @Mederic I created the DB using SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, and the actual CREATE TABLE statement, that is what you mean right?  I check the DB with a SQLite DB Admin program.  Changes persist when adding, but not deleting.  I can verify this by checking in the software I mentioned.

Comment: David Build your project in Release and go to the Release directory and launch exe you will see the changes persist

Comment: @Mederic Well, the deletion did persist like you said it would.  However, in debug mode, my INSERT's persist, and my DELETE's don't.  Based on what you said, that shouldn't be the case.  I am so confused.

Comment: @Mederic No clue why but I solved my own problem.  I was able to make my changes persist in Debug mode, but I had to delete a previous created DB and remake it, I think it may have been a schema change I made during debugging.  :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete my DB and recreated it, fixed the problem.  Think it was a small schema change I made during debugging.

Comment: glad you fixed it